# monitor ios url redirect timepoint when I use " [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:click_url]]"

Tags: ios, redirect

I‘m developing an ad sdk for iOS, there's a question now. It will open an url by Safari when user click an imageAd, I use this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:click_url]]
```

click_url is an urlString, it will redirect to appstore. There is requirement to record the redirect timepoint, I test the code to find a way to work it out.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxxx];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

the delegate method to record the redirect request and the timepoint

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"====================================");
NSLog(@"will send request\n%@", [request URL]);
NSLog(@"redirect response\n%@", [response URL]);
return request;
```

}
there is a problem, the request of the method "OpenURL" is not the same request of the "NSURLConnection", so what should I do when I use openURL to record the redirect information.

Thank you everyone's answer, I have solved this in another way. UIWebView:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSLog(@"%@",request.URL.absoluteString);
return YES;
```

}

I have replaced the "openurl" to "UIWebView", the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

openURL method allows to open another application installed in device. there no request sent.
you can record timepoint just before calling this method:

```
//add some code to record timepoint by using [NSDate date] (i suppose)
...some code ...
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:click_url]];
```

let me know if this respond on your demand. if not could you provide more details :)

Comment: the click_url will redirect to be an url such as "https://itunes.apple.com/app/idxxxxxx" to open the appstore (sdk for advertisement), the original url redirect to the itunes url, I need calculate the timeused for the redirect

Comment: and you need to log the timestamp when the user click on click_url?

Comment: for example, the first url request timepoint is 2016/1/25 10:10:10.111  redirect url request timepoint is 2016/1/25 10:10:11.222, I will get the time used 1 second 111 nano second

Comment: this little difference is it very important in your process?

Comment: Yes，the requirement is record the time long between the two jump.